# Should a game loop be placed inside an AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am making an android game which is made up of a game loop that is constantly running as well as use of the android UI stuff. So they need to be in separate threads to work concurrently.

I am planning to put the game loop inside an AsyncTask however it says in the developer.android documentation that

> AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)

My game loop will in theory be operating indefinitely and almost always for more than a few seconds. Is the asynctask the right place to put this then or is there another preferred method to split up a game loop and the UI operations

Comment: `AsyncTasks` and `UI` don't work very good example you can't use UI in `doInBackground` but on `onPostExecute` you can

Comment: I'm not putting UI stuff inside the AsyncTask i just want to run a while(true) loop inside one while the game is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AsyncTasks** are for short operations only, as the documentation has stated. Also, they usually do some work that shouldn't interfere with the UI. Hence, **"Async"** and **"Task"**.

What you should use instead is a new Thread. This is called **Multi-Threading**. There are a lot of Game Frameworks out there which will have problems with android's UI. Though you have not stated what UI Operations you are talking about, but if you plan to use the android's widgets(UI), you could call **Activity.runOnUiThread()** to run a code on the UI Thread, for example, changing a TextView's text.

Here is a snippet on how you would create a never ending loop in a new thread(*or something like this, i dont remember if the function is private*):

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    private void run() {
        while(true) {
            //your code goes here
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Essentially I'm making a turn based combat system that will use the android's built in XML buttons, text etc to allow the user to choose what to do but in the background a constant loop will check who's turn it is and if it isn't the users, calculate what the AI is going to do. I think your answer will help with this. Should the `new Thread()` be created inside an activity class or is there a way to implement it as a standalone.

Comment: You could use this anywhere. The thread will run just fine. And, since it is a different process from the UI Thread, this wont block any operations the Android UI has.

Answer (score 1):

Although `AsyncTask` allows you to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads, it should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most).

To keep things simple, you could use a `Handler`, or even better, research about the various APIs provided by the `java.util.concurrent` package.

```
import android.os.Handler;

// Create the Handler
private Handler handler = new Handler();

// Define the code block to be executed
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      // Insert simulation processing code here

      // Repeat 60 times per second
      handler.postDelayed(this, 1000 / 60);
    }
};

// Start the Runnable immediately
handler.post(runnable);
```

Remember that multi-threading is the easy part. Correct synchronization is hard.